# Find MIME type for image with no extension

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I'm hacking together a little Dropbox image slideshow. I use the Dropbox Public folder to share the index.html file which looks in the 'img' folder for a bunch of images to create slides.

I do this with the following, it's hacky but works

```
var findFiles = function(slideLimit){
  var limit = slideLimit;
  var img = [];

  for(var i = 1; i < limit; i++){

    var src = "<li class='slide slide-"+i+"'><img src='img/"+i+".png' onerror='imgError(this);''></li>"
    $('.frame ul').append(src);

  }

}
```

That works great, but I'd like to provide a solution that doesn't rely on the user having to use .png.

I was hoping omitting the extension would work on Dropbox but turns out no:

```
    var src = "<li class='slide slide-"+i+"'><img src='img/"+i+"' onerror='imgError(this);''></li>"
```

I've been racking my brains, ideally I'd like

```
if( mimeType = png)
   i + '.png'
else if (mimeType = gif)
   i + '.gif'
etc
```

Bit stuck for solutions. Anyone got any good ideas? Might require me taking different a different direction...

Comment: Give it an option to set the extension type.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the reply, not quite sure what you mean though, any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: `var findFiles = function(slideLimit, ext){ ext = ext || "png";`

Comment: @epascarello How does this determine what 'ext' is required? I'm aiming for a simple solution for people not comfortable with html/js/css.

Comment: There is no way to determine what the file type it is. You could do some sort of test by loading an image and seeing if it errors and than swapping, but it is just a waste of an http call when you can tell the user to look at an extension and do this.

Comment: Why would these users not be able to upload images that have an extension? Approximately 100% of images already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best way, make the users tell you the extension**

```
var findFiles = function(slideLimit, ext){
    var limit = slideLimit,
        img = [],
        lis = [];
    ext = ext || "png";   
    for (var i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        lis.push("<li class='slide slide-"+i+"'><img src='img/"+i+"."+ext+"' onerror='imgError(this);''></li>");
    }
    $('.frame ul').append(lis.join(""));
}
```

**Ping the server for the file, downside it takes time to keep hitting the server to see if the file it there**

```
var findFiles = function(slideLimit){
    var limit = slideLimit,
        img = [],
        lis = [],
        extList = ["png","gif"];

    function testExt () {
        var ext = extList.shift();
        if (ext) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                load(ext);
            };
            img.onerror = testExt;
            img.src="img/1." + ext;
        }
    }

    function load (ext){
        for (var i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
            lis.push("<li class='slide slide-"+i+"'><img src='img/"+i+"."+ext+"' onerror='imgError(this);''></li>");
        }
        $('.frame ul').append(lis.join(""));
    }

    testExt(); 
}
```

[note both code snipplets are untested, wrote them here in the editor]